# Operating with 2 tuples in pyspark - spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following row with two tuples,

```
[(('a', 'nexus4', 'stand'), ('-5.958191', '0.6880646', '8.135345'))]
```

The first part is a tuple which is formed with 'a' person index, 'nexus4' mobile model, and 'stand' what the person is doing , and the other tuple are the x,y,z coordinates from where the person is.

I have to group all by the first tuple, and the calculate min, max and avg from the first tuple to all the data x,y,z corresponding to him.

Here is an example from the output:

```
> User,Model,gt,media(x,y,z),desviacion(x,y,z),max(x,y,z),min(x,y,z)
> nexus4,stand,-3.0,0.7,8.2,2.8,0.14,0.0,-1.0,0.8,8.2,-5.0,0.6,8.2
```

Any idea about how to access to each element grouped from my first tuple to calculate min , max, and avg from it?

Here is the code I have developed:

```
# Data loading

    lectura = sc.textFile("Phones_accelerometer.csv")

    datos = lectura.map(lambda x: ((x.split(",")[6], x.split(",")[7], x.split(",")[9]),(x.split(",")[3], x.split(",")[4], x.split(",")[5])))

    sumCount = datos.combineByKey(lambda value: (value, 1), lambda x, value: (x[0] + value, x[1] + 1), lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```

Comment: what are `gt,media(x,y,z),desviacion(x,y,z),max(x,y,z),min(x,y,z)` and ``-3.0,0.7,8.2,2.8,0.14,0.0,-1.0,0.8,8.2,-5.0,0.6,8.2`?

Comment: I have answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110803/pyspark-grouping-and-calculating-data/49113823#49113823) please upvote if the information is useful.