# Sum tuples values to calculate mean - RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the following tuple.

```python
#                                 x           y        z
[(('a', 'nexus4', 'stand'), ((-5.958191, 0.6880646, 8.135345), 1))]
#           part A (key)               part B (value)         count
```

As you can see, I have a tuple which is my Key(PART A), I have another tuple which is my Value (PART B) and the number which is my count of different values from my Key Part.

My code for doing this is the following one.

```python
# Cargo los datos
lectura = sc.textFile("asdasd.csv")

datos = lectura.map(lambda x: ((x.split(",")[6], x.split(",")[7], x.split(",")[9]),(float(x.split(",")[3]),float(x.split(",")[4]), float(x.split(",")[5])))) 

meanRDD = (datos.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)))
```

Ok, now I want to SUM all the values that have the same KEY, to calculate the MEAN from X column, Y column or Z column.

I think I can do it by using reduceByKey, but I'm not applying this function correctly.

Example of my code that is not working:

```python
sum = meanRDD.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0][0] + y[0][1],x[0][1] + y[1][1], x[0][2] + y[1][2]))
```

I know after that I have to apply another MapValues function to divide my values by my count part, but the sum isn't working correctly.

example "asdasd.csv" file

```python
 Index,Arrival_Time,Creation_Time,x,y,z,User,Model,Device,gt
0,1424696633908,1424696631913248572,-5.958191,0.6880646,8.135345,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
1,1424696633909,1424696631918283972,-5.95224,0.6702118,8.136536,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
2,1424696633918,1424696631923288855,-5.9950867,0.6535491999999999,8.204376,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
3,1424696633919,1424696631928385290,-5.9427185,0.6761626999999999,8.128204,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
```

My key is a tuple (Model, device, gt) my value is (x,y,z)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the complete solution using `reduceByKey`

```
lectura = sc.textFile("asdasd.csv")

datos = lectura.map(lambda x: ((x.split(",")[6], x.split(",")[7], x.split(",")[9]),(float(x.split(",")[3]),float(x.split(",")[4]), float(x.split(",")[5]))))

meanRDD = datos.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1))\
               .reduceByKey(lambda ((x1, y1, z1), a1), ((x2, y2, z2), a2): ((x1+x2, y1+y2, z1+z2), a1+a2))\
               .mapValues(lambda ((x, y, z), sum): (x/float(sum), y/float(sum), z/float(sum)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know but I am receiving this error. d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
  File "<ipython-input-4-5306951b7b8c>", line 8, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I guess you are trying to get like x[0][0] when you can only get x[0]. If you share some sample lines of asdasd.csv then I can help you debug it

Comment: @fiticida, I updated my answer :) it should work now :)

Comment: First of all thanks, the code is correct, but I read that the use of parenthesis is now deprecated, I'm using Py3, and the tuples su such lambda ((x1,y1,z1),a1) and the other one, the console marks it as invalid syntax, as you can see in this img ; https://ibb.co/ceEea7

Comment: the error is because you haven't formated the code . there are spaces before reducebykey and before last mapValues. Remove the spaces and you should be fine . moreover I would recommend you to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49113823/5880706 . It would be more helpful :) and you can upvote that post if you find it helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, if I'm a bit tired, but after proving a lot this ideas, I think the error I'm getting is about what I said in my last msg.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-25-2bde6ac73d85>", line 8
    meanRDD = datos.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda ((x1, y1, z1), a1), ((x2, y2, z2), a2): ((x1+x2, y1+y2, z1+z2), a1+a2))
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166416/discussion-between-fiticida-and-ramesh-maharjan).